# insert multiple values into one table using split function. is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having one column order_id which is coming from customer_order table as a FK in `customer_order_products` which having 
3 columns:

- `order_id`,
- `product_id` and
- `quantity`.

I want to insert them simultaneously into one table so that it will show us like this :::

```
order_id     product_id     quantity
1              20             3
1              21             2
1              17             5
```

it means customer customer made order for 3 different products having quantity as mentioned above and generated order_id is 1.

how can i implement this.
plzzz help is needed

Comment: I think you need to provide more description about your issue, from what you give, I don't see a need for split function either.

Comment: actually i want to pass number of product_id and quantity at the same time. so that they linked up with each other.only order_id coming from customer_order. product_id and quantity are coming in a array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, plain `INSERT` will suffice in your case and will allow you to insert multiple rows with one statement

```
INSERT INTO customer_order_products
    ([order_id], [product_id], [quantity])
VALUES
    (1, 20, 3),
    (1, 21, 2),
    (1, 17, 5);
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d37f/1)**

Comment: @SandipRakshak Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.customer_order
 (
  order_id int
  )

CREATE TABLE dbo.customer_order_products 
 (
  product_id int,
  order_id int,
  quantity int
  )  

INSERT dbo.customer_order
VALUES(1)

INSERT dbo.customer_order_products 
VALUES(20, 1, 2),
      (20, 1, 1),
      (21, 1, 1),
      (21, 1, 1),
      (17, 1, 5)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#NewTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#NewTable
SELECT c.order_id, p.product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
INTO dbo.#NewTable
FROM dbo.customer_order c JOIN dbo.customer_order_products p ON c.order_id =  p.order_id
GROUP BY c.order_id, p.product_id

SELECT *
FROM dbo.#NewTable
```

Result:

```
orde_id product_id quantity
1       17         5
1       20         3
1       21         2
```